# Sum of String Pattern?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

> I have a Pandas DataFrame like :

```
ID        Traverse

001        1->1->1->2->3->1
002        13->13
003        2->3->13->15
004        5->6->3
005        16->7->7->7->7->8
006        4->4->3->5
007        5->5->1->1->1->2
```

> Output Should Be Like :-

```
1 to 1 : 4
1 to 2 : 2
2 to 3 : 2
4 to 4 : 1
3 to 5 : 1
13 to 13 : 1
7 to 7 : 3
.
.
.
So On
```

It's basically identifying the pattern and counting the occurrence of it and giving the output for a DataFrame like this.

I wrote a query like :-

```
df.Quad.str.contains(r'1->1').sum()` #To get 1->1
```

But it's adding up the rows which contain pattern like 1->1 but not adding individually

Note : 1->1->1 should give an output 1 to 1 : 2 (Likewise)

Comment: Interesting question. What have you done so far?

Comment: I wrote a query like :- 
df.Quad.str.contains(r'1->1').sum() #To get 1->1

But it's adding up the rows which contain pattern like 1->1 but not adding individually

Comment: This is easy: get all the X->X combinations into a python list, then use collections.Counter() to count how many you have. No need to start messing with dataframes.

Comment: You are contradicting the counts in the question.

Comment: @arjunbhasin should it? Should it not be 2? Otherwise `1->1` would give 2.

Comment: @FHTMitchell Yes, it is giving 2 as an answer because 2 rows contains such pattern but output requirement is something different.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Can you try and be a bit more clear? Show more examples in the question.

Comment: Yes, please. 
If it's 1->1->1->1 
Output should be 1 to 1 : 4 (this is the final count it should make)

Comment: .... But in your question you said `4 to 4 : 1,
3 to 5 : 1,
13 to 13 : 1` -- how is that possible if `1->1->1` makes 3 and `1->1->1->1` makes 4 which implies`1->1` makes 2. How would you get a 1?

Comment: Yes! What's contradicting in it? 
If it would have been 3->5->3->5 then it would have been 3 to 5 : 2 
It's basically telling how many times this thing has come up rather than counting the rows which contain such pattern

Comment: 1->1->1 makes 2, 1->1 makes 1, how many times 1 has gone to 1.. we are counting that

Comment: "1->1->1 makes 2" but literally 8 comments up you said "1->1->1 should give an output 1 to 1 : 3" -----

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I corrected it now. Really sorry!

Comment: 1->1->1 makes 2 only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

df = <your dataframe>

count = Counter()
for row in df['traverse']:
    nums = list(map(int, row.split('->')))
    for index, value in enumerate(nums[:-1]):
        count[value, nums[index + 1]] += 1

for key, value in sorted(count.items()):
    print('{k[0]} to {k[1]} : {v}'.format(k=key, v=value))
```

Output:

```
1 to 1 : 4
1 to 2 : 2
2 to 3 : 2
3 to 1 : 1
3 to 5 : 1
3 to 13 : 1
4 to 3 : 1
4 to 4 : 1
5 to 1 : 1
5 to 5 : 1
5 to 6 : 1
6 to 3 : 1
7 to 7 : 3
7 to 8 : 1
13 to 13 : 1
13 to 15 : 1
16 to 7 : 1
```

Comment: Can you also tell how we can count the Traverse values? 
Like, 1->1->1->3->4, this got 5 values.